# Add two different Materialize chips auto complete in same page with two different set of values

Tags: materialize, jquery-ui-autocomplete, materialized-views

I am designing once application where user can select customers and location. To implement this i am using materialize auto-complete feature. This working fine when i am implementing either of them. I am not able to find out any way where two chips auto-complete can have two different set of values for suggestion.

My target is:

1st Chips auto-complete will suggest the list of customers.
2nd chips auto-complete will suggest the list of locations.

I am stuck as materialize chips autocomplete API is working only when i am using $('**.chips-autocomplete'**).material_chip

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the process twice, once for each input. If you add a class or id to each then that should be easy enough to distinguish them:

```
$('#customers.chips-autocomplete').material_chip

$('#locations.chips-autocomplete').material_chip
```

You'll need to load the various autocomplete data separately for each as normal.